# How to store awk that has multiple backslashes as a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, awk, backslash, parentheses

I'm new to bashes but learning quickly.  One thing that stumps me is how to store an awk output as a variable if it contains multiple backslashs.  I have awk code to tell me everything between the two terms "1\1\" and "\@" (quotation marks not included).  I put an extra backslash behind each backslash.  The echo command works fine:

```
#!/bin/

FILENAME=$1
$echo awk '/1\\1\\/,/\\\\@/' $FILENAME
```

I try to store it as a variable via the regular way:

```
VAR=$($echo awk '/1\\1\\/,/\\\\@/' $FILENAME)

echo $VAR
```

I get a totally different section of the text file I'm analyzing.  I figure that the parentheses alter the meaning of a backslash, but I can't seem to find a way to store the string I am getting as a variable without using parentheses.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Edit: A major portion of the input file:

```
 Atom   3 needs variable   1=   1.4272969666 but is    0.9695781041
 Input z-matrix variables are not compatible with final structure.
 1\1\CRUNTCH-C1950-1-9\FOpt\RB3LYP\CC-pVTZ\H2O3\DK0178\21-Nov-2013\0\\#
 p B3LYP/CC-PVTZ opt\\Peroxide Molecule\\0,1\H,-0.2455786307,0.24093160
 48,0.0173467521\O,-0.1623823861,-0.3287313,0.7975033131\O,1.2337882601
 ,-0.2361247615,1.0791204051\O,1.4541296394,0.9715988133,1.8071520489\H
 ,1.2170466675,0.7056779744,2.7089056027\\Version=EM64L-G09RevB.01\Stat
 e=1-A\HF=-226.7854316\RMSD=3.950e-09\RMSF=2.016e-05\Dipole=-0.2755823,
 0.261353,0.1046274\Quadrupole=-1.3992237,-2.043705,3.4429287,-1.030514
,1.5582408,-0.1409701\PG=C02 [C2(O1),X(H2O2)]\\@
 ALL SCIENCE IS EITHER PHYSICS, OR STAMP COLLECTING.
```

The part I get the first time:

```
 1\1\CRUNTCH-C1950-1-9\FOpt\RB3LYP\CC-pVTZ\H2O3\DK0178\21-Nov-2013\0\\#
 p B3LYP/CC-PVTZ opt\\Peroxide Molecule\\0,1\H,-0.2455786307,0.24093160
 48,0.0173467521\O,-0.1623823861,-0.3287313,0.7975033131\O,1.2337882601
 ,-0.2361247615,1.0791204051\O,1.4541296394,0.9715988133,1.8071520489\H
 ,1.2170466675,0.7056779744,2.7089056027\\Version=EM64L-G09RevB.01\Stat
 e=1-A\HF=-226.7854316\RMSD=3.950e-09\RMSF=2.016e-05\Dipole=-0.2755823,
 0.261353,0.1046274\Quadrupole=-1.3992237,-2.043705,3.4429287,-1.030514
,1.5582408,-0.1409701\PG=C02 [C2(O1),X(H2O2)]\\@
```

The part I get the second time:
     ,1.5582408,-0.1409701\PG=C02 [C2(O1),X(H2O2)]\@05,3.4429287,-1.030514

Thanks!

Edit 2 (Sorry this is getting rather long) The code and error message I got for answer 2:

Input code:

```
#!/bin/

file=$1

$ cat file
abc
1\1\
def
\@
ghi

$ awk '/1\\1\\/{f=1} f; /\\@/{f=0}' file
1\1\
def
\@

$ var=$(awk '/1\\1\\/{f=1} f; /\\@/{f=0}' file)
$ printf "%s\n" "$var"
1\1\
def
\@
```

Error:

```
[dave@server ~]$ bash sshell.sh peroxide.out
sshell.sh: line 5: $: command not found
sshell.sh: line 6: abc: command not found
sshell.sh: line 8: 11def: command not found
sshell.sh: line 9: @: command not found
sshell.sh: line 10: ghi: command not found
sshell.sh: line 12: $: command not found
sshell.sh: line 14: 11def: command not found
sshell.sh: line 15: @: command not found
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `file' for reading (No such file or         directory)
sshell.sh: line 17: $: command not found
sshell.sh: line 18: $: command not found
sshell.sh: line 20: 11def: command not found
sshell.sh: line 21: @: command not found
```

Comment: There is nothing regular about the code you posted :-). Post some sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: SSCCE please. Example input, expected output, actual output, and code *copied and pasted* as you executed it.

Comment: What do you think `#!/bin/` at the top of your script does?

Comment: VAR=$($echo awk '/1\\1\\/,/\\\\@/' $FILENAME), is it echo or $echo ?

Comment: latter.  If I ignored the $ before echo it would just give me the words awk '/1\\1\\/,/\\\\@/' $FILENAME

Comment: Then you can  totally remove $echo, you still can get the value you want

Comment: Your last script contains interactive code like displaying the terminal prompt `$` in the beginning of a line.. You cannot have such code inside the script.. it should be executed (without the `$`) at the command prompt of the terminal window.. (Your script also contains output from running the terminal commands, such output cannot be placed inside the script file)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with this:

```
$ cat file
abc
1\1\
def
\@
ghi

$ awk '/1\\1\\/{f=1} f; /\\@/{f=0}' file
1\1\
def
\@

$ var=$(awk '/1\\1\\/{f=1} f; /\\@/{f=0}' file)
$ printf "%s\n" "$var"
1\1\
def
\@
```

Now - if that's not exactly what you want, update your question to include some sample input and expected output.

Don't ever use `awk '/start/,/end/'` as it makes trivial things like this slightly briefer, but requires a complete re-write for anything even marginally more interesting.

Comment: Thanks!  It says command not found for each part; what should I do differently?

Comment: What says command not found? Update your question to show the command you executed and the output and error message. Copy/paste them from your terminal.

Comment: Did it.  Sorry about the delay - I'm still figuring out the formatting here.

Comment: man bash and google hello world as you have no idea about shell syntax, you need to start from absolute basics.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
#! /bin/bash

var=$(awk 'BEGIN { RS="" } {
    match($0,/1\\1\\(.*)\\@/,a)
    print a[1] }' input.txt)
echo "$var"
```

where `input.txt` is your input file..